# MySQL: select columns based on other column value

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table named t,

```
focus, H, Li, Be, B, C
    H, 1,  2,  3, 4, 5      
   Be, 6,  7,  8, 9, 10
```

I want to write a MySQL query to select columns in this table based on the values of `focus` column, for example, from table t it will return:

```
H, Be 
1, 3
6, 8
```

I know it's very easy to write:

```
select H, Be from t
```

However, this is not a dynamic resolution if the content of table t changed. For example, assuming table t now is:

```
 focus, H, Li, Be, B, C
     B, 5,  0,  0, 4, 4      
     C, 8,  9,  1, 7, 3
```

Previous code doesn't work. It still returns the same result instead of:

```
B, C      
4, 4
7, 3
```

My question is, is it possible, we wrote a MySQL script to select the columns based on the values of `focus` column?

Comment: This table design makes little sense to me. I guess what you want is a kind of dynamic pivot, so you should be able to find help in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Comment: You can't do this in SQL, it has to be done in a stored procedure to generate a dynamic query.

Comment: Possible [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)? What are you really trying to accomplish with this? I'm with Barmar. I don't understand your table design, either.

Answer (score 0):

instead os selected the column based on focus value, why do you select focus based on the column. See the below example

```
Declare @sql varchar(10),@SQLString varchar(100)
Set @SQL = ‘H’

Set @SQLString  = ‘Select focus, ‘+@sql +
‘From tablet
Where focus = ‘+@SQL

Exec @SQLString
```